# Javascript remove empty items from sides of an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

This is exactly what I mean but in Javascript: [PHP remove empty items from sides of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231136/php-remove-empty-items-from-sides-of-an-array)

I'm looking around the cleanest way to do it. I wondering if there is a better way than loop the array manually.

Here an example:

```js
const fullArray = new Array(10);
fullArray[3] = 1;
fullArray[5] = 1;
fullArray[7] = 1;
console.log('Input:', fullArray);

const trimedArray = new Array(4);
trimedArray[0] = 1;
trimedArray[2] = 1;
trimedArray[4] = 1;
console.log('Output:', trimedArray);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take the keys of the array (which takes only properties that *exist on the array* - it won't take sparse indicies like 0 to 2, or 4, or 6, or 8 in your example), you can call `Math.min` and `Math.max` on them:

```js
const fullArray = new Array(10);
fullArray[3] = 1;
fullArray[5] = 1;
fullArray[7] = 1;

const keys = Object.keys(fullArray);
const min = Math.min(...keys);
const max = Math.max(...keys);
const result = fullArray.slice(min, max + 1);
console.log(result);
```

Another option, by taking just the ends of the keys array:

```js
const fullArray = new Array(10);
fullArray[3] = 1;
fullArray[5] = 1;
fullArray[7] = 1;

const keys = Object.keys(fullArray);
const min = keys[0];
const max = keys[keys.length - 1];
const result = fullArray.slice(min, Number(max) + 1);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's exactly ! The alternative option is better